# Can I wire a 2 wire case fan backwards?

Tags: fan, case

Can I wire a computer case fan backward so it spins in the opposite direction? I don't want it to fry and break. Also, can it go the opposite direction?

Comment: Did you look at the fan blades?  The fan blades are typically shaped for optimal airflow in only one direction of rotation.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to. Connect it correctly, and install it backwards. The mount is laterally symmetrical and there's a often an arrow pointing in the direction of the air flow.

Comment: +1 for essentially explaining the difference between a "push or pull" fan configuration in a single sentence

Comment: Well there might be diodes and other such things, depending on the design... but flipping it is just safer and more sensible